# Kivy: Switching between screens from Popup

Tags: python, kivy

I'm having trouble switching screens in kivy.
From MainScreen there's a button that will open a Popup.
Inside the popup there's a button that when pressed, DisplayScreen will be displayed.

Here's my python code.

```
#this is MainScreen class
class MainScreen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

    def displayConfirmationDialog(self):
        confirmationDialog = self.MainScreenConfirmationDialog()
        confirmationDialog.setMessage()
        confirmationDialog.open()

     #this is the function of the button
    def update(self):
          self.displayConfirmationDialog()

    #this is the popup class
    class MainScreenConfirmationDialog(Popup):


        def setYesButton(self):

            screenManager.add_widget(DisplayScreen())
            self.manager.current = 'display_screen'

#this is the DisplayScreen class
class DisplayScreen(Screen):
    pass
```

Here's my kivy code

```
<MainScreen>:
    Button:
        text: 'UPDATE'
        on_press:root.update()

<MainScreenConfirmationDialog>:
    GridLayout:
        rows: 3
        Label:
            id: lbl_confirmation
        Button:
            id: b
            text: 'YES'
            on_press: root.setYesButton()
<DisplayScreen>:
    name: 'display_screen'
    GridLayout:
        rows: 4
        row_force_default: True
        row_default_height: 40
        Label:
            text: 'HELLO'
            id: lbl_display_name
```

When I run this, it shows me an error

```
    File 'main.py', line 89, in setYesButton self.manager.current = 'display_screen'
AttributeError: 'MainScreenConfirmationDialog' object has no attribute 'manager'
```

Answer (score 0):

The Popup widget does not have access to the screenmanager.

## Solution

Since you have access to the global variable, `screenManager`, replace `self.manager.current = 'display_screen'` with `screenManager.current = 'display_screen'`